# Excel Reader - How to read numeric and string values from Excel file?

Tags: java

[image]

```
static Workbook book;
static Sheet sheet;

public static Object[][] getTestData(String sheetName) {
    FileInputStream file = null;
    try {
        file = new FileInputStream(TESTDATA_SHEET_PATH);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        book = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sheet = book.getSheet(sheetName);
    Object[][] data = new Object[sheet.getLastRowNum()][sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum()];
    // System.out.println(sheet.getLastRowNum() + "--------" +
    // sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum());
    for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum(); k++) {
            data[i][k] = sheet.getRow(i + 1).getCell(k).toString();
            // System.out.println(data[i][k]);
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Unfortuantely instead of zipcode 16946 I get the "16946.0" and for phone number i get "9.9839293847" in the console output. How this should be formatted to receive the exact number?

Comment: Is this SQA related? It seems just general development

Answer (score 0):

Found solution outside of my social network -
Enter number like this '16946 and save in excel row (This ' Single quote convert the value into numeric one)